# How to find item by name from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have listbox with Buttons. Every button have specific name -> button.Name = "button1".

I want to find specific button in listbox by Name.

I tried something like this:

```
if (listBox.Items.Contains(new Button().Name = "button2"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("TEST");
}
```

But it doesnt work.

How to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check: 1. If the item is a `Button` 2. If its name is the same (use `==` not `=` as in your code)

```
foreach(var i in listBox.Items)
{    
    if (i is Button && (i as Button).Name=="button2")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TEST");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your ItemsControl item with you then you can iterate its Visualtree to reach to your button using VisualTreeHelper

Recursive find child is explained in this post [How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls)